Are password saved in Google Password or other third parties also stored in Knox Vault?
Passwords saved in Samsung Pass will be stored in Knox Vault. So, are the passwords saved in Google Password or other third parties also stored in Knox Vault?

The question as you have posted can be answered easily - it is a clear NO.
In Knox vault there are never passwords stored in. The documentation states that Knox vault is used for storing:


Cryptographic keys to protect biometric data
Blockchain keystore credentials
Samsung Attestation Key (SAK)
All data in Credential Storage is encrypted using a Knox Vault-unique key. This prevents the data from being decrypted in other devices.


This is no surprise as hardware protected systems usually have very small storage (I assume a few KB), not enough to save a large list of passwords.
Even if the storage would be larger it wouldn't make sense to use it as password storage, because in difference to ´cryptographic keys which can be used by a HSM without letting the key come in touch with the less secure  Android OS system, a password always needs to be processed by the less secure Android system as it has to be sent to the server which processes and compares the password.
But as you can se from the documentation the cryptographic keys that are used to protect the passwords/credentials are stored in Knox Vault.
Even if you don't use the Google credential system instead of the one from Samsung the protection bases on the cryptographic keys from AndroidKeystore which is saved in Knox Vault, as described in this Samsung blog post:

The newly introduced Knox Vault is integrated into Samsung devices starting from the Galaxy S21, and its components are evaluated at EAL4+ and higher. By default, Knox Vault can:

Store sensitive data such as hardware-backed Android Keystore keys, the Samsung Attestation Key (SAK), biometric data, and blockchain credentials.
Run security-critical code that authenticates a user with increasing timeouts between failures and controls access to keys depending on authentication.



Thanks for the answer.
